# Google maps set bounds zoom level

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map that shows the users location and automatically zooms in.
I am wondering how I can set this zoom level as 'zoom' and 'maxZoom' isn't working. After some googling it seems that I need to set the bounds but wouldn't know where to start.
I am hoping to get it to zoom to around 12.

Here is part of the code:

```
jQuery('#map_canvas').gmap('getCurrentPosition', function(position, status) {
    if ( status === 'OK' ) {
        var clientPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        jQuery('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {'position': clientPosition, 'bounds': true});
        jQuery('#map_canvas').gmap('addShape', 'Circle', { 
            'strokeWeight': 0, 
            'fillColor': "#008595", 
            'fillOpacity': 0.25, 
            'center': clientPosition, 
            'radius': 15, 
            'clickable': false 
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the setZoom-method of the `google.maps.Map`-instance to apply a custom zoom **after** adding the marker

```
jQuery('#map_canvas').gmap('get','map').setZoom(12);
```